# Does $\hat{\theta} - \theta \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$ imply $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} -\theta) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$? Or vice versa?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have a sample of $n$ observations, and $\hat{\theta}$ is an estimator for the parameter $\theta$ (which is a constant).

From the following two convergence in probability statements:

1. $\hat{\theta} - \theta \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$
2. $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} -\theta) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$

Does (1) imply (2)? The other way around? Or (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2)?

Comment: 2 implies 1, but not the other way around

Comment: @Andrew $\theta$ should be a constant

Comment: @Snoop thank you. Yes, $\theta$ is a constant. I added this clarification in the original post

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $\sqrt n\hat\theta \to \sqrt n \theta$ because $n$ is on both sides of the limit.

Comment: As previously noted, 2 implies 1, but 1 does not imply 2. Just take the sample mean and recall the central limit theorem.

Comment: The counterexample is the sample mean and the central limit theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(2) \implies (1)$ we have:

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0,\;\; 0 \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}P(|\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta - \theta| > \epsilon) = 0 \implies 0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} P(|\hat \theta - \theta|> \epsilon) 
\leq   \lim_{n \to \infty}P(\sqrt{n}|\hat \theta - \theta|> \epsilon) = 0
$$

As pointed out in the comments $1$ does not imply $2$.